# Определенная длина нижней границы

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок с текстом, для которого мне нужно использовать border-bottom, но подчеркнуть не всю нижнюю границу, а лишь пару центральных букв. (например в слове "выполнить" нужно чтобы граница была лишь под "олн".

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи [псевдоэлемента](http://htmlbook.ru/index.php/css3/before) можно сделать блок и задать ему позиционирование снизу по центру блока с текстом.

Так же, можно применить единицу измерения [`ch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/length#%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), которая равна одному узкому символу (`n` например)

```css
.small-border {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.small-border::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 3ch;
  height: .2em;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="small-border">выполнить</span>
```